# Pattern not found in Expect.pm

Tags: perl, expect

I tried the following example out, why is it not found?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;

my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->expect(10, 'match me exactly', '-re', "match me exactly") or print "Not found\n";
```

At first, I tried with 'match\s+me\s+exactly' according to Expect.pm example, but it
didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to launch the child whose output you're expecting to match.

Comment: I am new to Expect, but can I have have the first 'match me exactly' as the expression, and the second 'match me exactly' as the pattern?

Comment: You want to do `'match me exactly' =~ /match me exactly/`?

Comment: To @ikegami: I tried both ways but they didn't work. 1) my $exp = new Expect;
$exp->expect(10, '-re', 'match me exactly' =~ 'match me exactly') or print "Not
found\n";   and             2) $exp->expect(10, 'match me exactly' =~ /match me exactly/) or print "Not found\n";

Comment: No, just `'match me exactly' =~ /match me exactly/`. That's why you used is you want to match `match me exactly` against `match me exactly`.